# Exclude root folder from batch zip

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, 7zip

i want to batch zip files without the root folder.

I have a structure like this

```
- root-folder
-- directory
-- file
-- file
-- directory
```

I want to have a zip file containing only the sub files and directorys

```
- Zip File
-- directory
-- file
-- file
-- directory
```

Currently im getting:

```
- Zip File   
-- root-folder
--- directory
--- file
--- file
--- directory
```

Im using following batch script:

```
for /d %%X in (*Pictures) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "Pictures-EN.zip" "%%X\"
```

Comment: So you only want the subfolders within the root folder of "Pictures"?

Comment: Try just changing `"%%X\"` to `"%%X\*"`.

Comment: Didnt worked out @Compo

Answer (score 0):

In the parent of root-folder do:

```
tar -caf output.zip -C root-folder *
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to filter the folders as you can see in my currently using code `(*Pictures)`

Comment: "i want to batch zip files without the root folder." - isn't this your requirement? Or you mean you must use 7z.exe?

Comment: Youre right, but i have different folders and i only want specifics to be included in the zip, e.g. in my code (*Pictures)